# Can a person still travel in other EU countries after being deported and banned from Norway?

Tags: schengen-visas, norway, deportation, italian-residents

My friend is deported and banned from entering Norway for years. But he has a Carta Soggiorno here in Italy. Can he still travel in other EU countries? How can he check his status with other EU countries before visiting them? He is a non-EU citizen.

Comment: It probably depends on why your friend was deported and banned from entering Norway.  Can you add that information?

Comment: they say illegal stay or overstayed plus illegal working.. they dont give him any lawyer. and he appealed once,no good immigration lawyer can't help him.

Comment: I suspect that for a nonviolent offense such as this he can still travel to other Schengen states.  But it's also possible that his status in Italy could be in jeopardy.  Is the *carta di soggiorno* issued in connection with EU free movement, or is it a regular *permesso di soggiorno?*

Comment: it's long term .. "illimitata" they issued it even after the deportation. he was accepted by the immigration police in the airport after norway deported him back in italy. and they let him stay here and after he manage to get the long term visa "ILLIMITATA" unlimited it means.

Comment: But is it issued because he is the family member of an EU citizen?  If it is, then he can certainly go to other Schengen countries with his family member.  If it is not, or he wishes to travel without his family member, then I do not know how to find out what his status is in other Schengen countries.

Comment: NOPE, it is not issued because of the family but because he really working here, and he just coming back in forth in Norway. Thank you so much for ur time.. Have a nice day Ahead !

Comment: [UDI decisions are individual](https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/expulsion/#link-1043), so we can't usually tell you whether your friend was banned from Schengen (entered on the Schengen Information System). It's likely Italian residence changes things, and someone may know enough to answer, but I would encourage you check the expulsion paperwork in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

It is up to UDI (Norwegian Immigration) to determine if they would be registered in the Schengen Information System (SIS) database:

*"The UDI will also decide whether you will be subject to a prohibition against entry to all the Schengen countries. In that case, you will be registered in the database Schengen Information System (SIS)."*

If information is entered into SIS by UID, it is up to the individual country to determine their appropriate course of action (this is why he can have residence in Italy, but possibly be barred from other Schengen countries). Your friend does, however, have the right to request that information, if any, is entered in SIS by UID.

*"If you wish to find out what information is registered about you, or ask for incorrect information to be corrected or deleted, you must contact the National Criminal Investigation Service (NCIS, or Kripos in Norwegian).  You will find more information about how to proceed and the request form which you need to fill in at the NCIS website (external website)."*

https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/schengen-information-system-sis/